# Can't filter object out of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I'm trying to use the following to filter an object out of an array:

```
foo = [{foo: 'bar'}, {baz: 'bar'}];
bar = foo.filter(function(i) {
  return i !== {foo: 'bar'}
})
```

When I log `bar` afterwards, I get the full array.

The following code

```
foo.filter(function(i) {
  console.log(i === {foo: 'bar'});
  console.log(i);
  console.log({foo: 'bar'});
  return i !== {foo: 'bar'}
})
```

returns:

```
false
{ foo: 'bar' }
{ foo: 'bar' }
false
{ baz: 'bar' }
{ foo: 'bar' }
[ { foo: 'bar' }, { baz: 'bar' } ]
```

What am I missing here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work:

```js
const foo = [{foo: 'bar'}, {baz: 'bar'}];
const bar = foo.filter(function(i) {
  return i.foo !== 'bar'
});

console.log(bar);
```

You should compare the property 'foo' itself instead of comparing both objects

Comment: I guess this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Almost, `i` is the actual object. So you just need to compare `i.foo` to the string `bar` instead. Doing a comparison against an object like `i === {}` will never work. You would need to compare all of the properties in `i` and your `object`. There are plenty of deep compare helpers / examples out there if you were wanting that sort of thing.

[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
/*
foo = [{foo: 'bar'}, {baz: 'bar'}];
bar = foo.filter(function(i) {
  return i !== {foo: 'bar'} // <-- You can't compare i to an object like this
})
*/

/**
* Array.filter will provide you with each object in your array.
* `i` is already the object in which you're trying to compare
* so you just need to access the property you want to compare (foo)
* and then compare if to the string 'bar'. i !== { prop: 'val' }
* will not give you accurate results
*/
foo = [{foo: 'bar'}, {baz: 'bar'}];
bar = foo.filter(function(i) {
  return i.foo !== 'bar'; // i is already the object. Access the property and then compare
});
console.log(bar);
```

If you think you need to run a deep compare, take a look at this: [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Using a shorter notation

```js
let foo = [{foo: 'bar'}, {baz: 'bar'}];
let bar = foo.filter(i => i.foo !== 'bar');

console.log(bar);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to open up the object for the comparison. Something like this would work

```
foo = [{foo: 'bar'}, {baz: 'bar'}];
bar = foo.filter(function(i) {
   const [key, value] = Object.entries(i)[0];
   return key === 'foo' && value === 'bar'
})
```

Comment: (Didn't down vote you). I like your catch on comparing the property AND value. but I think op is strictly after the object where the property foo is equal to bar